# Multiple API Calls using Promise.all fine to show results in console but Issue with State

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am making multiple API calls in react, and I am able to get data perfectly in console But when I am trying to set the state in order to display also in UI , Its not working. According to my analysis, there is something wrong with setting up the data into state.

Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const data = [
    {
      id: "IT58A2158"
    },
    {
      id: "ITD856741"
    },
    {
      id: "IT85TKACQ"
    }
  ];


class Actions extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Ids: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            Authorization: "Bearer 000000-0000-0000",
        };
        console.time('.map()')
        Promise.all(
          data.map(id => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
              fetch(`https://example.com/api/Item/${id.ID}?realm=xyz`, { headers })
                .then(response => {
                  return new Promise(() => {
                    response.json()
                    .then(response => {
                        this.setState({Ids: response.data}); // I am trying here to set all data to State
                        console.log(response);
                        resolve()
                      })
                  })
                })
            })
          })
        )
        .then((res) => {
            console.timeEnd('.map()');
        })

      }

    render() {
        const { Ids } = this.state;
        if (!Ids) {
            return <h1>Please Wait....</h1>
        }

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid" style={{ backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7' }}>

                <table id="table-to-xls" className="table table-responsive table-striped display nowrap"  >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Id</th>
                            <th scope="col">Date</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody> 
                        {/* wants to render data here but not working */}
                        {Ids.map((record) => (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{record.id}</td>
                                <td>{record.dueDate}</td>
                                <td>{record.title}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Actions;
```

Thanks for your support :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting a new value of `Ids` to the individual response data for each API call. Should you instead be adding the value into the Ids array?

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  Ids: [...prevState.Ids, response.data]
}));
```